# Ifstream file getting cleared when reading from line

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read characters separated by white space from an input textile in C++. I've successfully opened the file and been able to iterate through it. However, whenever I try to assign variables from the characters in the file, the lines seem to be cleared. The first line's variables are set correctly, but are not after the first line. I am not sure if I am accessing the infile incorrectly, if there is a flag I am missing, or if there is a better method of approaching accessing the characters.

Code:

```
int lineNumber = 0,*linesMaxVal = new int[lineCount];
string line;
while (getline(infile, line)) {

    cout << "line # is " << lineNumber << " line val is: " << "'" << line << "'" << endl;

    int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,max;
    infile >> x1 >> x2 >> x3 >> x4 >> x5;
}
```

If the line "infile >> x1 >> x2 >> x3 ... etc" is removed, the output is as follows (correct)

```
line # is 0 line val is: '0 0 0 0 0'
line # is 0 line val is: '1 2 3 4 5'
line # is 0 line val is: '5 4 3 2 1'
line # is 0 line val is: '5 100 1000 10000 10500'
line # is 0 line val is: '99999 99999 99998 99999 99999'
line # is 0 line val is: '-1 0 0 0 -1'
line # is 0 line val is: '-9999 -9999 -9998 -9999 -9999'
line # is 0 line val is: '50 1234 457 789 7'
line # is 0 line val is: '123240 -124 -453 234 -99999'
line # is 0 line val is: '234 235 -109 0 12'
line # is 0 line val is: '777 987 234 345 111'
line # is 0 line val is: '12 0 -19 27 19'
line # is 0 line val is: '0 0 0 0 0'
line # is 0 line val is: '-99 -900 45 20 10'
line # is 0 line val is: '13 -56 99 123 90'
line # is 0 line val is: '0 0 1 -11 -1'
line # is 0 line val is: ''
```

Otherwise, if the infile line is left in and the variables are defined, the output is as follows.

```
line # is 0 line val is: '0 0 0 0 0'
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
line # is 0 line val is: ''
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
infile >> x1 >> x2 >> x3 >> x4 >> x5;
```

Reads all of the numbers on the line but leaves the newline character in the stream.

Then you go back to the head of your loop and run:

```
getline(infile, line)
```

Which immediately sees a newline, so it gives you an empty string, eats the newline and moves on.

The big issue here is that the extraction operator (`>>`) leaves the whitespace it stops at in the stream (in this case a newline), while `getline` eats whatever delimeter it stops on. Mixing the two can cause little hiccups like this.

One possible fix could be to add an `ignore` after your extraction operators to get the newline out of the stream.

---

After some talk [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44384420#44384420), it looks like you want to loop through the file and find the largest value on each line. I'd suggest using a vector to store each line's values and using the algorithm library to find the max:

```
//Our temp vector. It'll hold a line worth of ints
vector<int> line(5);

while(true) { //one loop = one line

    //Loop and read 5 ints (one line's worth) into the vector 
    for(int x = 0; x < 5 && infile >> line.at(x); x++) { }

    if(!infile) { break; } //if we read through everything, we're done!

    //find the biggest value in the vector
    int biggest = *max_element(line.begin(), line.end());

    //Do some things with it...
    cout << "Biggest is: " << biggest << endl;
}
```

For a working demo, see here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/3Sk2Ed)

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. How would an ignore flag be used in this context?

Comment: @JohnHardingII you could do `infile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`. See here for more: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Comment: Hmm, that's definitely an improvement as the variables are being filled now, however it is skipping every other line which is undesired.

Comment: @JohnHardingII yes, because you're reading that line into `x1, x2, ...` and then not doing anything with it. So you're actually reading in every line, you're just only printing every *other* line.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but after running a few more tests it does not seem to be reading every line into the variables, instead actually skipping them. Is there a step I'm missing in order to preserve every line?

Comment: @JohnHardingII once you've extracted from the stream, you can't read them from the stream again. `getline()` will extract a full line until it hits a newline. `infile >> x1 >> x2 >> ...` will extract a full line (except the newline at the end). Every loop you're extracting two lines from the stream but only printing the one you got from `getline`

Comment: Oh, okay. What would bet the best method of using the second line that is being extracted but is currently unused?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182516/discussion-between-scohe001-and-john-harding-ii).